# What are DeferredLoading and LazyLoading in Microsoft Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading, deferred-loading

Could you explain what are DeferredLoading and LazyLoading in Microsoft Entity Framework (and in general)? Is it the same think? What are the differencies? Do you have a good link about the subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same thing. It was for a time called Deferred Loading, it's now called Lazy Loading. See this link: [Getting Started with Entity Framework 4 – Lazy Loading](http://geekswithblogs.net/iupdateable/archive/2009/11/26/getting-started-with-entity-framework-4-ndash-lazy-loading.aspx)